# c++ function scope

Tags: c++, scope

I have a main function in `A.cpp` which has the following relevant two lines of code:

```
B definition(input_file);
definition.Print();
```

In `B.h` I have the following relevant lines of code:

```
class B
 {
   public:
     // Constructors
     B(void);                                                    
     B(const char *filename);
     ~B(void);

     // File input
     int ParseLSFile(const char *filename);

     // Debugging
     void Print(void);

     // Data
     int var1; 
     double var2;   
     vector<char* > var3;   
     map<char*, vector<char* > > var4; 
}
```

In `B.cpp`, I have the following function signatures (sorry for being redundant):

```
B::B(void)
  : var1(-1),
    var2(numeric_limits<double>::infinity())
{
}

B::B(const char *filename)
{
  B *def = new B();
  def->ParseLSFile(filename);
}

B::~B(void)
{
  // Free memory for var3 and var 4
}

int B::ParseLSFile(const char *filename)
{
  // assign var1, var2, var3, and var4 values
}

void B::Print(void)
{
  // print contents of var1, var2, var3, and var4 to stdout
}
```

So when I call `Print()` from within `B::ParseLSFile(...)`, then the contents of my structures print correctly to stdout. However, when I call `definition.Print()` from A.cpp, my structures are empty or contain garbage. Can anyone recommend the correct way to initialize/pass my structures so that I can access them outside of the scope of my function definition?

Thanks.

Comment: Wherever in your code you have  char *, you should really consider using std::string - particularly for the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making

```
B *def = new B();
def->ParseLSFile(filename);
```

in your constructor you should simply write

```
ParseLSFile(filename);
```

This means that your current object members would be initialized by using `ParseLSFile` function. You could probably name that function `InitFromFile` to preserve some naming logic.

Then your code will transform to:

```
B object_name(filename);
object_name.Print();
```

and (not exact, but just for you to understand the underlying mechanics) this would mean somthing like

```
Create empty object of type B
Initialize it from file using InitFromFile()
Call Print() to display the contents of this object
```

Comment: Thanks for the function name suggestion. I've been thinking of a better way to name it and I like yours.

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor that takes a `const char*`, you dynamically create *another* instance of the class and use that instead of the current instance.  Instead of

```
B *def = new B();
def->ParseLSFile(filename);
```

you need to just call

```
ParseLSFile(filename);
```

so that you are operating on the object being constructed.  As it is now, you have a resource leak.

On an unrelated note, you should not use a pointer as the map key.  As it is now, it is near impossible to access an element by its key because only a pointer comparison will be done; the string values pointed to by the `char*` will not be compared.  You should use `std::string` as the key type instead.